# Will the Intel DZ87KLT-75K motherboard fit into the Corsair CC-9011017-WW Case?

Tags: motherboard, case

Will the [Intel DZ87KLT-75K Motherboard](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-board-dz87klt-75k.html) fit into the [Corsair CC-9011017-WW Case](http://www.corsair.com/en/carbide-series-300r-windowed-compact-pc-gaming-case.html)? To me it seems by reading the documentation that the motherboard is too big, but I'm not sure as I have no experience with this and I was told that all ATX motehrboards are compatible with all ATX cases.

Comment: Exactly which documentation makes you think it won't fit?

Comment: @techie007 the PDF provided with the motherboard, and the actual size of the case.

Comment: @techie007 Sorry derped, I forgot I should translate the width into height as it gets mounted on it's side...

Comment: Take the measurement of the motherboard and compare them to the motherboard dimision specifications of the case itself.

Comment: @Ramhound I did, but I forgot to flip the dimensions to the side. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the links you provided:

Intel DZ87KLT-75K Motherboard Form factor: **ATX**

Corsair CC-9011017-WW Chassis Compatibility: **ATX** and Micro ATX motherboards

Since they both conform to the [ATX form factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX), then they should be compatible.

When putting ATX boards into an ATX chassis, the only gotchas tend to be when it comes to motherboard component placement and various over-hangs within the chassis itself (like drive cages banging into full length video adapters for example).